# How to Properly Type My Curve's Formula

Tags: unity, c#, curves

I'm creating an RPG game (using C# in Unity API) that uses a leveling system. I went to the Desomos Online Graphing Calculator and created the following curve representing the levels based on experience: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bsvkba4qg1. Note that the Y-intercept is at approximately (0, 1).

My `Character` class has the following fields representing the experience curve from above:

```
public float experience { get; set; }

public int level {
    get
    {
        float level = experience / 120;
        level += 1.123f;
        level = Mathf.Log(level);
        level *= 20;
        return Mathf.FloorToInt(level);
    }
}
```

However, when the game begins and `experience` defaults to 0 as floats do, `level` returns 2. When `experience` is `100`, `level` returns `13`. Clearly there is some error on my part. Have I entered my formula wrong? If so, how can I fix it, and if not, what else might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Desmos graph, you are using log base 10, however your unity function is using log base e (natural log, often abbreviated ln). To specify that you want log base 10, you need to add a second argument like the example below. See [Mathf.Log()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Log.html) for details.

```
 level = Mathf.Log(level,10);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was something simple. It seems I have forgotten a thing or two from my school days. Cheers!